# Angular Material Chips rtl

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I've started to use Angular Material in my application.
I'm using md-chips control and I want to show it in right to left direction.
(the chips on the right side and the placeholder on the left)
I've reviewed to angular-material.css and found that almost all directives have dir=rtl styles but md-chips haven't.

Does somebody encounter this problem?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want RTL support or something similar to it using Angular Material's chip component, you need to change some properties.

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but this solution is pretty robust.

here's the code I added:

## SCSS

I wrote this in SCSS for clarity. If you're using regular css, you can click on `view compiled` in the codepen demo I added

```
md-chips.rtl {
    .md-chips md-chip {
        float: right;

        ._md-chip-remove-container {
            right: initial;
            left: 4px;
        }

        &:not(.md-readonly) ._md-chip-content {
            margin-left: 24px;
        }
    }

    ._md-chip-input-container {
        float: right;

        input {
          direction: rtl;
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, in my html, I add the rtl class for this to work:

```
<md-chips class="rtl" ...>...</md-chips>
```

And if I'm using a custom chip template, I also add dir="auto" to it so it will decide on the direction of the text based on the content

```
<md-chip-template dir="auto">...</md-chip-template>
```

If you only want to replace the direction of the input and chips but use a LTR language, you can just change the `float: left` of all chips and the input:

```
.md-chips md-chip {
    float: right;
}

.md-chips ._md-chip-input-container {
    float: right;
}
```

here's a working demo with both RTL and LTR chips.
Notice that the readonly checkbox works pretty nice with the RTL chips as well

http://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/WxjQqg?editors=1100